# Authentication error when trying to install or uninstall using Ubuntu Software Center (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, software-center, software-installation

when trying to install or uninstall from Ubuntu Software Center (14.04). I'm getting the error message

```
**Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available. (org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.85'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages**
```

when I try to install or uninstall anything from the Center.

I'm running this through Crouton on a Chromebook. Is there anything I can do to fix this issue?

Answer (score 12):

I was faced with the same problem and the following solution fixed my case:

1. check whether you have  `policykit-1-gnome` installed. (I only had policykit-1 installed before). If not, install it using apt-get.
2. run `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1`. Now try to start software center from launcher and software should be able to be installed successfully.
3. add `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` to your startup applications. press super key and search "startup applications" in all programs. Open it and click "add" to add this command line.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi, Winter and @hmayag, you have clearly nailed the issue. It helped to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanx. It fix me. Who knows how it happened and how to fix without adding to "startup applications"?

Comment: What is the supper key? the windows key doesn't do anything for me, is there another way to open the `startup applications`?