# Most of my software just disappeared (Kubuntu)

Tags: kubuntu, backup, pam

Amarok, konsole, dolphin, volume control, and a lot of other software just disappeared after I restored pam.d to default last night.  Is there some way for me to restore my software without restoring the pam.d file configs?  Should I just backup /home/ and do a reinstall?

Comment: What did you do exactly to "restore pam.d to default" ? Can we see a log of what happens ? You say that your applications disappeared, I assume that you've check with `dpkg -l <name>` that the package was missing and not only a launcher icon ?

Comment: sudo pam-auth-update --force

I can't dpkg -l since the terminal has disappeared from both the search function and the launcher's application menu.  I would manually look for the binary, but dolphin disappeared as well.

Answer (score 1):

Does `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` work, and get everything back?

If you can't access the terminal, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then login in and execute the command.

Comment: There is no terminal, but I'm trying that with the deb file from the repositories.

edit:  And the deb install failed

Comment: Then first of all try getting the *.deb file of the KDE terminal.

Comment: Does Ctrl+Alt+1 work?

Comment: @Tim that would be F1, not 1.

Comment: I've gotten the deb.  SOftware center crashed when I tried to install it, trying with synaptic now

Comment: Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available. (org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name':  ':1.85'}): org.debian.apt.install-file

Comment: That can be solved: see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/218961/software-cant-be-installed-or-removed-because-the-authentication-service-is-no).