# Server with GUI, can't get elevated privileges with Chrome Remote Desktop

Tags: server, gnome, software-center, google-chrome, remote-desktop

I've set up a home media server using ubuntu server and plex. Initially I was going to try and run command line only, but, being somewhat of a noob, I ended up installing a desktop environment. I use chrome remote desktop to connect, and here's where the problem comes in. None of the desktop applications can get elevated privileges. The dialog for the su password just doesn't appear. This is the error software center gives me

> Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service >is not available. (org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus->name', {'name':  ':1.794'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages

This only occurs when connecting through remote desktop. If I sit down physically at the machine and connect a monitor and log in, things function as they should.

Per the post [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218961/software-cant-be-installed-or-removed-because-the-authentication-service-is-no), trying to start polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1 returns the following error

> (polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1:17295): polkit-gnome-1-WARNING **: >Unable to determine the session we are in: No session for pid 17295

I'm not sure if the problem is with linux configuration, chrome remote desktop, or a third thing. I have another linux machine (running kubuntu desktop) which I don't believe is affected, so I'm pretty sure there's a configuration issue somewhere.

Can anyone help me get this sorted out?

EDIT:  gksu and sudo work from command line, except when launching software center.  Not sure if its related or not, but [here's](http://pastebin.com/2VhakWsh) the error for it.

Comment: I do have remote access through ssh going, but some things are still easier to manage in the gui (scheduled tasks, editing scripts, etc).  My setup is perfect except for this issue.  Thanks for the comment, though.

Comment: yeah, it's not a problem of being unable to do things as admin, just getting elevated privileges for GUI apps like software center doesn't work.

Comment: Weird that gksu works just fine, but the standard policy-kit complains about what session we're in.  Ironically, I can't use gksu (or sudo, for that matter) to launch software-center.  It spits out an error.