# No permission to install anything from ubuntu software center

Tags: permissions, software-center, chromebook

I'm using crouton on a Samsung pro 2 Chromebook. I'm currently running GNOME on Xenial. Unless I download via terminal, I get this message:

```
You are not allowed to perform this action.
```

And when I expand to see details I get this:

```
org.freedesktop.PolicyKit.Error.Failed: ('system-bus-name', {'name': ':1.83'}): org.debian.apt.install-or-remove-packages
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available. "](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218961/software-cant-be-installed-or-removed-because-the-authentication-service-is-no)

Comment: @galoget This question doesn't appear to be a duplicate of "Software can't be installed or removed because the authentication service is not available." according to the accepted answer of this question which was posted by Isserus.

Comment: @karel You're right, good observation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it this is your first time running a Chroot you've installed on your Chromebook? In other words, this is the first time you've encountered this problem, yes?

In short, you'll have to use the gksu, instead of sudo, whenever you require the graphical interface to grant you the permissions you seek. It'll be simple, and it'll be quic--

Until someone more knowledgable than myself graces you with their presence, in the meantime, open up that terminal, and let's get you going with some software installations.

Inside a terminal type the following command:

```
gksu gnome-software
```

This will prompt you to enter your password, and then the gnome software store will run, with you having all them sweet, juicy permissiones!

You'll have to run the software store using this command every time you wish to install software from it, otherwise, using "sudo" inside a term to install programs will work as usual.

This won't by any means break your desktop, so you're totally good.
It is, however, worth mentioning that there are things one should be aware of when running gksu, but I'll let the next bloak explain that.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 18.04 I could not find the command `gksu`, or a way to install it. But this worked for me.

```
sudo -i gnome-software
```

Comment: This worked for me one Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 19.10, we always use `sudo apt install mydeb.deb` this will prompt us to enter password once password entered then the install operation has always been smooth like we regluarly update using `sudo apt-get update`.

Try reinstalling software center by using this command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall software-center gnome-software` and resolve permission issues if there are any by using following command to grant ownership:

```
sudo chown <user>:<user> /usr/bin/gnome-software
```